# Filtering Core Data Objects for multiple conditions

Tags: swift, core-data

Working on a part of my application that involves filtering the objects being sent to the tableview. I have tried using a CompoundNSPredicate but the result was nothing showed. If I do each filter separately I can call the fetchrequest for 1 type of objects but when I try to use a second line calling the second type of objects under the same loop condition the second objects don't appear at all. Example for where I am:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Cards")
    let warriorpredicate = NSPredicate(format: "cardClass = %i", 1)
    let shamanpredicate = NSPredicate(format: "cardClass = %i", 2)
    let roguepredicate = NSPredicate(format: "cardClass = %i", 3)
    let paladinpredicate = NSPredicate(format: "cardClass = %i", 4)
    let hunterpredicate = NSPredicate(format: "cardClass = %i", 5)
    let druidpredicate = NSPredicate(format: "cardClass = %i", 6)
    let warlockpredicate = NSPredicate(format: "cardClass = %i", 7)
    let magepredicate = NSPredicate(format: "cardClass = %i", 8)
    let priestpredicate = NSPredicate(format: "cardClass = %i", 9)
    let minionpredicate = NSPredicate(format: "cardClass = %i", 10)
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    if ((passedDeckObject?.classSelected.classname = "Warrior" ) != nil) {
        fetchRequest.predicate = warriorpredicate
    } else {
        if ((passedDeckObject?.classSelected.classname = "Shaman" ) != nil) {
            fetchRequest.predicate = shamanpredicate
            fetchRequest.predicate = minionpredicate
        } else {
            if ((passedDeckObject?.classSelected.classname = "Rogue" ) != nil) {
                fetchRequest.predicate = roguepredicate
            }

            if ((passedDeckObject?.classSelected.classname = "Paladin" ) != nil) {
                fetchRequest.predicate?.isEqual(paladinpredicate)
                fetchRequest.predicate?.isEqual(minionpredicate)
            } else {

                if ((passedDeckObject?.classSelected.classname = "Hunter" ) != nil) {
                    fetchRequest.predicate?.isEqual(hunterpredicate)
                    fetchRequest.predicate?.isEqual(minionpredicate)
                } else {
                    if ((passedDeckObject?.classSelected.classname = "Druid" ) != nil) {
                        fetchRequest.predicate?.isEqual(druidpredicate)
                        fetchRequest.predicate?.isEqual(minionpredicate)
                    } else {
                        if ((passedDeckObject?.classSelected.classname = "Warlock" ) != nil) {
                            fetchRequest.predicate?.isEqual(warlockpredicate)
                            fetchRequest.predicate?.isEqual(minionpredicate)
                        } else {
                            if ((passedDeckObject?.classSelected.classname = "Mage" ) != nil) {
                                fetchRequest.predicate?.isEqual(magepredicate)
                                fetchRequest.predicate?.isEqual(minionpredicate)
                            } else {
                                if ((passedDeckObject?.classSelected.classname = "Priest" ) != nil) {
                                    fetchRequest.predicate = priestpredicate
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return fetchRequest

}
```

Some of the code looks different but that's cause I was testing each one with different lines I gave examples using both ways I have tried minus the compoundpredicate attempt which showed nothing at all.

Comment: So if the classname is Shaman, for example, you want to select cards with cardClass = 2 or 10?

Comment: correct! thats exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: You are on the right path with NSCompoundPredicate: does `fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate.orPredicateWithSubpredicates(shamanpredicate, minionpredicate)` work?

Comment: it should but I get a extra argument in call when I do it like that. I tried making the warriorpredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .And....etc method but it never worked as well for different reasons.

Comment: i noticed there is also a .andPredicateWithSubpredicates but it also gives the same argument when you try and do the command like you presented

Comment: Oopps.  `fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate.orPredicateWithSubpredicates([shamanpredicate, minionpredicate])`  Note the "[" and "]".

Comment: ah yes is orPredicateWithSubpredicates the way to go or is andPredicateWithSubpredicates?

Comment: **orPredicate** : you want to include cards where cardClass is 2 OR cardClass is 10.  If you use andPredicate, it will only include cards where cardClass is 2 AND 10.  For a given card, it can't be both 2 and 10, so you would get empty results.

Comment: Ah thank you for clarifying that! There is one final issue because it actually worked but for some reason now it will only display the first if and doesn't check the rest of the else statements for the objects...

Comment: OK.  There's a neater way to do it than all those if statements - but probably we should switch to chat to explain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this came in multiple ways. There were many methods that could be used to actually do what I was looking to do but the simplest most elegant solution was:

```
func listFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    let requiredClassName = passedDeckObject!.classSelected.classname
    var requiredCardClasses = [Int]()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Cards")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    switch(requiredClassName) {
        case "Warrior":
        requiredCardClasses = [1,10]
        case "Shaman":
        requiredCardClasses = [2,10]
        case "Rogue":
        requiredCardClasses = [3,10]
        case "Paladin":
        requiredCardClasses = [4,10]
        case "Hunter":
        requiredCardClasses = [5,10]
        case "Druid":
        requiredCardClasses = [6,10]
        case "Warlock":
        requiredCardClasses = [7,10]
        case "Mage":
        requiredCardClasses = [8,10]
        case "Priest":
        requiredCardClasses = [9,10]
        default:
        requiredCardClasses = [10]
    }
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"cardClass IN %@", requiredCardClasses)

    return fetchRequest

}
```